# `git describe` with gitlab python API

Tags: git, gitlab, tags, version, conan

Is it possible to get the equivalent to `git describe --tags` with the [gitlab python API](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-usage.html)?

I want to shallow clone my repo on the gitlab runners for performance, but still get the last tag as version information for [conan builds](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/capture_version.html?highlight=git#how-to-capture-package-version-from-scm-git).

Comment: Same question here. Trying to figure that out. But no success yet. I wan't to calculate the version online without checkout only by specifing the commit-id.

If I loop through commit.parent_ids, it gets too long over the time. The only thing I would need is to calculate distance to the next tag within a regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Same question here. I need to calculate the distance from a commit-id to a certain tag (project/version). There are multiple project in there, so many different ways are possible.

Got a solution now:

Example:

```py
import gitlab
import pprint
from argparse import Namespace
import datetime


# helper to find all tags - limit to your needs
def find_tags(tags):
    result = []
    for tag in tags.list(all=True, as_list=False):
        result.append(tag)
    return result


_fast_cache = {"page": 0}


# gets a commit in an fast manner
def get_commit(project, commit_id, **kwargs):
    global _fast_cache

    if kwargs.get("direct", True):
        commit = project.commits.get(commit_id)
        _fast_cache.update({commit.id: Namespace(title=commit.title, id=commit.id, parent_ids=commit.parent_ids,
                                                 dateref=datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(commit.committed_date))})
        return _fast_cache[commit_id]

    while commit_id not in _fast_cache:
        count = len(_fast_cache.keys())
        current_page = _fast_cache["page"] + 1
        for commit in project.commits.list(page=current_page, ref_name=kwargs.get("branch", commit_id),
                                           per_page=100,
                                           **kwargs):
            if commit.id not in _fast_cache:
                _fast_cache.update(
                    {commit.id: Namespace(title=commit.title, id=commit.id, parent_ids=commit.parent_ids,
                                          dateref=datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(
                                              commit.committed_date))})
        _fast_cache["page"] = current_page
        if len(_fast_cache.keys()) == count:
            return None
    return _fast_cache[commit_id]


def walk_project(project, HEAD, tag, **kwargs):
    def as_commit(c, direct=False):
        if isinstance(c, str):
            _commit = get_commit(project, c, direct=direct, **kwargs)
            if _commit is None:
                return None

            return _commit
        return c

    seen_map = {}
    depth = 0

    HEAD = as_commit(HEAD)
    lookup = {0: HEAD.id}

    TAG = as_commit(tag.target, direct=True)

    if TAG.dateref > HEAD.dateref:
        return None

    while len(lookup.keys()) > 0:
        key_item = sorted(lookup.keys()).pop(-1)
        current = lookup[key_item]
        del lookup[key_item]

        if current not in seen_map:
            data = as_commit(current)
            if data is None:
                # print("Nothing found?")
                return None

            seen_map[data.id] = dict(depth=depth, parents=data.parent_ids)
            for x in data.parent_ids:
                d = as_commit(x)
                lookup[d.dateref] = d.id

            if data.id in tag.target:
                return tag.name + "-" + str(depth) + "-g" + HEAD.id[:10]

            # abort in case that too many commits must be traversed
            if depth >= 1000:
                return None

            # debug output
            print(f"[{depth}][{data.id}] {data.title}")
            depth += 1

    return None


def main():
    gl = gitlab.Gitlab("https://gitlabserver.com", private_token="mytoken")

    project = gl.projects.get("pretty-tagged-project")
    print(project.name)

    current_head = project.commits.get("a commit to start ")
    print(current_head.attributes)
    print(current_head.parent_ids)

    tags_names = find_tags(project.tags)

    pprint.pprint(tags_names)

    for tag_name in tags_names:
        version_number = walk_project(project, current_head.id, tag_name, branch=current_head.id)
        print(tag_name.name, version_number)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: Yes. But there is missing the part where to calculate and match the tags... I'm not getting on that. An it might would help the question starter either.

Comment: I tried to [start here](https://github.com/elsamuko/gitlab-describe/blob/main/gitlab-describe.py), but was too lazy to continue this yet.  
Best would be official solutions from gitlab or even git.

Answer (score 0):

We can program like this to implement `git describe --tags`:

1. Get all tags of projects, and sort tags in reverse order according to the commit time of tags.
2. For each tag, use **[Gitlab Merge Base API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#merge-base)** to get the common ancestor of your current commit id and the tag's commit id; if the result is the same as the tag's commit id, it is what you want.

Currently, the latest version of python-gitlab is v3.7.0, it does not implement the `merge_base` API, but it is easy to call HTTP API directly by requests.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I solved it by creating a new shallow checkout for the current branch with only the logs/tags. Sorry, not using the python api, but if you are open to a git CLI solution, this might help

I use these lines in a "setup" job in my pipeline. Other jobs can then depend on the "setup" job, and source that build.env

```
- tmp_dir=$(mktemp -d -t ci-XXXXXXXXXX)
- cd ${tmp_dir}
- git clone --filter=blob:none  --no-checkout --single-branch --branch ${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH} ${CI_REPOSITORY_URL} .
- echo "GIT_DESCRIBE=$(git describe --tags ${CI_COMMIT_SHA})" >> $CI_PROJECT_DIR/build.env
```

I hope someday this is just a standard exposed variable. There is an open issue for it https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/3822